# Authentification failed with Google maps API ( Android )

Tags: android, api, google-maps

i have a problem of authentification with the Google Maps service API, i followed the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) , i configured really well my API key, i started a new Application with googleMap Activity, i replaced the values string with the API key, and i run the application in my mobile phone who has google services.
each time i see in the log the same problem

`01-01 21:59:12.110 21943-21993/? I/b: Sending API token request.
01-01 21:59:42.225 21943-21993/? E/b: Authentication failed. Timeout while trying to contact the server.`

Comment: Have you given Internet permission in manifest file.?

Comment: it's really strange, i have created the same example with different package name and different API key of corse, and it's working, i don't think that internet permission is necessary, now, i have the same project sample , one working and the other not.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me once the app was perfectly configured. So it was already working. The problem was solved restarting the device as some upgrading was taking place in the system and it needed to reboot to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forgot to enable the map services in google console !!

If you say everything is correct ,Try uninstalling and reinstalling the application. because apparently if you make one mistake on the configuration the system caches the failed authentication and your maps won't work even after fixing your configuration.

So try following the docs and guides on configuring Google Maps Api on Android but every time you change something on your configuration uninstall and reinstall.